# jQuery Collection Cache

Tags: jquery, optimization, collections, caching

Does anyone know a good way to cache a collection of objects returned by a selector.

```
var $platforms = $(".platforms");    
var i = 0, l = $platforms.length, current;

for(;i<l;i++) {
    current = $($platforms[i]); //calling jQuery() in a loop. Should be cached
}
```

The above code creates a jQuery instance of each element returned by `$(".platform")` when it should be cached. Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To literally get an array of jQuery wrappers of elements, you can use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) like this:

```
var $platforms = $(".platforms").map(function() { return $(this); }).get();
```

Then in your `for` loop `$platforms[i]` will be a jQuery object.

---

It depends what you're after though, there's [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) like this:

```
$(".platforms").each(function(i,elem) {
  var current = $(this);
});
```

Or use [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to get a jQuery wrapped element at that index in your loop, like this:

```
for(;i<l;i++) {
  current = $platforms.eq(1);
}
```

It all depends on what you're after....*why* are you looping through the elements? Most jQuery operations operate on sets, not individual elements, so for example `$(".platforms").bind(...)` would bind to *all* of the elements that selector found.

Comment: Very good point. Although `$(this)` is still calling the jQuery function and in my case (a game) that means a lot of function calls that isn't necessary. Need to find the `position()` for each. My current solution is to check it at onload, then cache the values in an array but was wondering if a nice solution existed.

Comment: @Louis - you could maintain an array of the jQuery wrapped version of the elements if you're repeatedly looping like this, for example: `var $platforms = $(".platforms").map(function() { return $(this); }).get();` then you can do `$platforms[i]` and it'll be a jQuery wrapper.

Comment: Nice, I like that! Could you add it to the answer so I can accept.